# Add a value to a variable that was created with _.map & _.range

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is there a function in lodash that will allow me to add an object to the
 front of an array that is dynamically created?

I'm creating a range of values

```
_.map(_.range(0, 100), function(x) {
    var range = {
        id: x,
        value: x
    };

    return range;
});
```

and I want to add an additional value to the beginning of range with the
 properties

```
 var additionalValue = {
    id: '-',
    value: '-'
 };
```

I thought

```
_.assign(range, additionalValue);
```

would work but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `unshift` here.

[Working Example](https://jsbin.com/zeqaxes/1/edit?js,console):

Once you're done with the map you can simply use `unshift` to 'push' to the front of an array:

```
var arr = _.map(_.range(0, 100), function(x) {
    var range = {
        id: x,
        value: x
    };

    return range;
});

 var additionalValue = {
    id: '-',
    value: '-'
 };

arr.unshift(additionalValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `unshift` I believe: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unshift.asp